# Test Complete : How to know the test function name, test file name and project name from within a test complete function

Tags: automated-tests, jscript, testcomplete

We are trying to execute a test function and we need to know the name of the test function ,the name of the current file and the name of the current project from within the test function.

something like

```
function TestGlobalSearchClientContacts(){
 var this_function_name = ??
 var this_file_name = ??
 .
 .
 .
 testcode 

}
```

How can this be done when using Test Complete ?
We are using JScript and TC version is 9

Answer (score 0):

To get the project name, use:

```
aqFileSystem.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Project.FileName)
```

To get the current function name, you can call this function:

```
function getCurrentFunctionName() {
  return arguments.callee.caller.toString().match(/function\s+([^\s\(]+)/)[1];
}
```

To get the current unit name, you need to run tests as *test items*. Then you can use:

```
function getCurrentUnitName() {
  return Project.TestItems.Current.ElementToBeRun.Caption.match(/Script\\([^ ]+) -/)[1];
}
```

You can also see the unit and function names in the Call Stack tab in the test log if you turn on `Log.CallStackSettings.EnableStackOn...` settings in your test.